# How to correctly retrieve data from a table passed from a function?

Tags: powershell, database

What I am trying to do is returning a table from a function (ListBuilds) that retrieves it from a database. Then places rows from that table into a ListBox so that a row can be selected. The problem is that I cannot access the data in the table.
The code in ListBuilds

```
$table = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $databaseServer -Database $databaseName -Query $sql      

Return $table
```

The code calling this places the table into an array, which I have a couple of write-hosts added to try and debug.

```
    $listTable = @(ListBuilds | Format-Table | Out-String)
    write-host "AA $listTable"
    write-host "aa $listtable[0].ScriptName"
```

The output from the writes are

```
AA 

ScriptName  ScriptVerNum ScriptLocation                     
----------  ------------ --------------                     

AAAA                   1 C:\win 10 Build tool\TestScript.ps1

BBBB                   1 C:\win 10 Build tool\TestScript.ps1

Test Script            1 C:\win 10 Build tool\TestScript.ps1

aa 

ScriptName  ScriptVerNum ScriptLocation                     
----------  ------------ --------------                     

AAAA                   1 C:\win 10 Build tool\TestScript.ps1

BBBB                   1 C:\win 10 Build tool\TestScript.ps1

Test Script            1 C:\win 10 Build tool\TestScript.ps1

[0].ScriptName
```

I was expecting `$listTable[0].ScriptName` to return just AAAA.

How do I access the contents of the table returned from the function?

Comment: you are using `Format-Table` ... and that DESTROYS your objects, and wraps the remnants in _formatting code_. [*grin*] use `Select-Object` instead if you want to use the objects instead of "stuff" intended for _final display on screen_ OR _final output to a plain text file_.

Comment: I could not get `Select-Object` to work but `$listTable[0].ScriptName` now does and thank you I now have a better understand of how powershell passes data around.

Comment: i'm glad that you got it working ... but PLEASE **_never, ever, ever use the `Format-*` cmdlets for anything other than FINAL output to the screen or FINAL output to a plain text file._** you get broken objects wrapped in _formatting code_, not the actual objects. take a look at the returned 4th item in this >>> `(Get-ChildItem -Path $env:TEMP -File | Format-Table)[3]` <<< note the red error text mentions `"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData"`. [*grin*]